# macOS Big Sur blocking gui internet access if certain connections to apple are denied, ping working

Tags: mac, big-sur, internet, firewall

I have the following problem: I use Little Snitch to block just about any connection to apple (please no advice on how important it is to allow updates etc, I know what I'm doing and why ;) ). This worked fine with High Sierra. I recently set up another Mac with Big Sur, and suddenly **gui internet access is blocked after system restart**.

I can ping via terminal, connection works fine. If I pause Little Snitch just before connecting to the internet for the first time, and reenable 1 minute later, everythings works fine, too - and continues to do so, until I restart the MacBook again.
So in short, Big Sur blocks gui internet access (i've tried 5 different browsers and some other apps) when certain startup connections are blocked. Does any of you have any idea which connections might be the cause of this?? I've experimented with enabling and disabling a number of them, but gotten nowhere so far.
I'm really grateful for any tipps and ideas!

co-der-in

PS: This seems like a grave privacy invasion to me... I basically can't use the MacBook unless it's allowed to check in with apple!

Comment: We don't know what you have blocked - *'just about any connection to Apple'* doesn't really tell us anything. Plus… it's going to be hard to find other people in a similar situation, as the vast majority of us freely connect with Apple all the time.

Comment: Hey Tetsujin - that's precisely the problem, there are so many many many processes connecting to apple, that it's a bit difficult to find the right one (or list them all here). This question is mostly directed at people who might have stumbled across this issue themselves. If you don't try to  prevent this data exchange with apple, you'll probably not be interested in testing in that direction...? (If you are interested, i'll get right at it and try to make a list )

Comment: You're going to have to unblock them and do them one at a time. There's no other way to determine what's causing this

Comment: It's probably checking that certificates are valid, so is not a privacy invasion, but a security feature.

Comment: i don't think it's about certificates - i only have to unblock them once after rebooting, afterwards everything works fine in the blocked mode

Comment: @Ezekiel yes, i'm afraid so... started doing that but lost patience, there are so many :( I thought I'd check first, if anyone else had the same issue.

Comment: What does "GUI Internet access" mean?  If you think you mean via a browser, exactly what is the failure?

Comment: Yeah, a screenshot would be great

Comment: No gui internet access means: I can ping via terminal (haven't done anything else), but various browsers, messenger, vpn gui apps cannot connect to the internet. Error messages depend on the app. I'm on it, will post some screenshots tomorrow at the latest. :)